# Better way to get document ID which was auto generated to create the doc or update an array inside the document Firestore / Firebase

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating one document per user to store the id's of the users bookmarks. I'm using addDoc so the ID of the created doc is generated by firebase. I want to check if that document exists to create a new one or update the old. I need to have a document reference to update the doc and I had a horrible time trying to figure out a way to get a hold of that auto generated ID. My code works but it feels really hacky - Is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
//Add a value to the bookmarks array for individual user
export const addBookmarkForUser = async (userAuth, showId) => {
  const bookmarkDocRef = collection(db, 'users', userAuth.uid, 'bookmarks')
  const bookmarkSnapshot = await getDocs(bookmarkDocRef)
  let userBookmarkDocId
  if(bookmarkSnapshot){   
    bookmarkSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      if(doc.id){
        userBookmarkDocId = doc.id
        console.log(userBookmarkDocId)
      }
    })    
  }  
  try {    
    if(!bookmarkSnapshot) {
      await addDoc((collection(db, 'users', userAuth.uid, 'bookmarks'), {
        favorites: [{showId: showId}],
      }))
    }else {
      const userBookmarkRef = doc(db, 'users', userAuth.uid, 'bookmarks', userBookmarkDocId)
      await updateDoc(userBookmarkRef, {
        favorites: arrayUnion({showId: showId})
      })}
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error creating bookmark', error.message);
  }
};
```

I know I will only have one document in there for each user - is there a better way to find the doc.id?

Here is the firestore structure -
[image: firestore1]

[image: firestore2]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your Firestore structure and also explain what is `bookmarkSnapshot` being queried for?

Comment: The bookmarkSnapshot is checking to see if there are any documents in the 'bookmarks' collection, and if there is, I get the document id. I'll edit the question to add the Firestore structure.

Comment: Can you tell what is the document ID used in bookmarks collection? As in, you must be looking if a document exists by ID right? Do you have that ID before you query?

Comment: No, I don't know the id, that was the problem. I don't know how to find the id that was auto generated - That if statement looks to see if there are any documents in the collection (There will be only one) and it pulls out the one ID in there. But like I said, it feels like a terrible way to get the ID and there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to check how many documents are present in a collection then you can use `getCountFromServer()` that loads the count without the actual document data.

```
import { collection, getCountFromServer } from 'firebase/firestore';

const bookmarkColRef = collection(db, 'users', userAuth.uid, 'bookmarks');
const bookmarksCount = (await getCountFromServer(bookmarksColRef)).data().count

console.log(`${bookmarksCount} documents found in ${bookmarksColRef.path}`)\

if (!bookmarksCount) {
  // no document exists, create new 
}
```

However, since you need the document ID and its data. You can run a simple query:

```
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

const bookmarkColRef = collection(db, 'users', userAuth.uid, 'bookmarks');
const bookmarksSnap = await getDocs(bookmarksColRef);

if (bookmarksSnap.empty()) {
  // no document
} else {
  const docData = bookmarksSnap.docs[0].data();
  console.log(docData)
}
```

Comment: I just get 
`Object {  }
<prototype>: Object { … }` when I log this. I don't see how how this gives me the ID.

Comment: @Peshwari_Naan when you log what? Can you please update your question with updated code. Also have you tried `bookmarksSnap.docs[0].id` ?

Comment: Ah - that was it - If I console log `bookmarksSnap.docs[0].id` than I get the ID I need. I could not find this anywhere in the documentation so I don't really see the benefit of using an auto generated ID if you need a ref for it in the future. At any rate - Thank you so much for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You can find the API reference [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.querysnapshot). `getDocs()` returns a `QuerySnapshot`. Then every `DocumentSnapshot` has `id` property whether it be auto generated or specified by you.